# Silverstripe 3: How to show date picker in CMS datagrid

Tags: silverstripe

I have a datagrid allowing the user to add events to an event page.

On it, I have 2 date fields so they can specify a start and end date. These fields do not show the date picker unless I comment out a line from DateField.js in Sapphire/javascript (line 12 - `if(!config.showcalendar) return;`).

Is there anyway to get the date picker to show without tampering with the core?

```
<?php
class Event extends DataObject{
    public static $db = array(
        'Title' => 'Varchar(255)',
        'StartDate' => 'Date',
        'EndDate' => 'Date',
        'Summary' => 'Text',
        'Content' => 'HTMLText'
    );

    static $has_one = array( 
        'WhatsOnCategory' => 'WhatsOnCategory',
        'EventImage' => 'Image'
    );

    public static $summary_fields = array(
        'Title' => 'Title'
    );

    public static $default_sort='StartDate';

    public function getCMSFields() {
        return new FieldList(
            new TextField('Title', 'Title'),
            new DateField('StartDate', 'StartDate'),
            new DateField('EndDate', 'EndDate'),
            new TextField('Summary', 'Summary'),
            new HTMLEditorField('Content', 'Content'),
            new UploadField('EventImage','Image')
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The DateField does not show the calendar popup by default, you have to configure it to do so.

Apply for all DateFields: (you could put this line at the top of your getCMSFields method)

```
DateField::set_default_config('showcalendar', true);
```

Apply to a specific DateField instance

```
return new FieldList(
    DateField::create('StartDate', 'StartDate')->setConfig('showcalendar', true)
    ...
)
```

Using the DateField::create method instead of new DateField allows you to call methods on that class directly in one line, which is nice. I think it's also best practise with SS objects.

**Update**

In SilverStripe 3, the global configuration can be set using the new config system.

ie. In your config YML

```
DateField:
  default_config:
    showcalendar: true
```

If you are using **DateTimeField**, to get the "per instance" configuration working you need to first call getDateField:

```
$myDateTimeField->getDateField()->setConfig('showcalendar',true);
```

If you would like a timepicker UI on the DateTimeField's Time field, you'll need to install the [TimePicker module](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-timepickerfield)and then:

```
$myDateTimeField->setTimeField(
    TimePickerField::create('StartTime[time]', '')
    ->addExtraClass('fieldgroup-field')
);
```

Comment: @kaiTaylor I've updated/extended my answer for you ^^